# why can't I create an ubuntu image via gcloud compute command?

Tags: google-compute-engine

why can't I create an ubuntu image via gcloud compute command? in addition, i didn't see any ubuntu version in the list when i used "gcloud compute images list" command to list all the available images? thanks.

Comment: Can you please edit the Q to show us exactly **what** you get from `gcloud compute images list`?  I see three Ubuntu images from project `ubuntu-os-cloud` among other images.  You don't?  Have you run `gcloud components update` lately...?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for reminding me. I indeed forgot to update the list. It works fine now.

Comment: Ruiliang Zhang, Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! @AlexMartelli, can you please move your solution into an answer which Ruiliang can then [accept](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What solved the issue, we hear from the OP, was running `gcloud components update` first, as I had recommended in a comment, to ensure `gcloud` functionality is up to date -- after which `gcloud compute images list` gives the proper listing and the `ubuntu` images can be installed.  Moving this info to an answer so it can be accepted, at @Misha Brukman's request.